# how to place two divs besides each other

Tags: html

On a web page, I have two divs. I would like to place the second div just right to the other one so that they're in a line.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the `float` CSS style. Set it to `left` for the first div. The second div will be placed just right of it (so long as there is enough space)

```
<div>
  <div style="float: left">
     <p> This div will be on the left</p>
  </div>
  <div >
     <p> This div will be on the right</p>
  </div>
  <!-- optionally, you may need to add a "clearance" element below the floating divs -->
  <div style="clear: both" ></div>
</div>
```

Note, that sometimes it may be necessary to give the floating divs a fixed width in order to achieve the proper horizontal layout.

```
<div>
  <div style="width: 100px; float: left">
     <p> 100px div will be on the left</p>
  </div>
  <div style="width: 200px">
     <p> 200px div will be on the right as long as there is enough 
         horizontal space in the container div
     </p>
  </div>
  <!-- optionally, you may need to add a "clearance" element below the floating divs -->
  <div style="clear: both" ></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

```
<div>
    <div style="float:left;"></div>
    <div style="float:left;"></div>
    <div style="clear:both;"><!-- usually leave this empty --></div>
</div>
```

You can also float:right; in order to make the divs align on the right side of the page.  The clear is VERY IMPORTANT.  In IE a lot of the time the float left/right rule is propagated to other elements to elements you did NOT intend to float.  Usually though; you don't pick up on this right away and it becomes a nightmare to figure out why your page looks like crap down the road.  So just make a habit of putting an empty clear div as the last sibling of any divs you decide to float.

Answer (score 2):

Most simple way is CSS float:

```html
<div id="div1">hello</div>
<div id="div2">world</div>
```

And the CSS:

```css
#div1 {float: left;}
#div2 {float: left; margin-left: 10px;}
```

[Simple test case](http://jsfiddle.net/37cng/).

After the floating divs add another one to clear the float so that further contents will be displayed fine:

```
<div style="clear: both;"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

`float` is a quick way, `inline-block` is another quick way and has some advantages over float such as not needing a `clear:both` element.

here's an example with both methods http://jsfiddle.net/dGKHp/

HTML:

```
<div id="floatExample">
    <div>Float Left</div>
    <div>Float Right</div>
    <br />
</div>

<div id="inlineBlockExample">
    <div>Left</div><div>Right</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#container {width:600px;margin:0 auto;}

#floatExample div {float:left;background-color:#f00;width:50%;}
#floatExample br {clear:both;}

#inlineBlockExample div {display:inline-block;width:50%;background-color:#ff0;}
```

This is a pretty good write-up on ins and outs of `inline-block`: http://robertnyman.com/2010/02/24/css-display-inline-block-why-it-rocks-and-why-it-sucks/