# Two divs besides one another with content wrapping from second div

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm looking for a solution to position two divs one besides the other in a `<td>`.
The first div element is an image that's fixed size.
The second div element is a link (text) of unknown length.

I want to wrap the second div's content on resize of the browser window but the wrapped content should not appear below the image (div-1) and should not flow out of row.

Expected behaviour should be as shown below :

[image]

Current behavior is as shown below :
[image]

There is a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9463735/two-divs-one-besides-the-other-without-wrapping), but wrapping is not expected there and I want wrapping in my second div.

thank you for your help

Code I currently have is :

```
<td class="infoElement" data-ng-if="::!item.empty">
 <div style="overflow: auto">
    <div style="display: inline-block" class="ListIcon" data-context-link="item"></div>
    <div style="overflow: hidden; display: inline-block;">
        <a data-ng-bind="::item.displayName"></a>
    </div>
 </div>
</td>
```

Comment: Do you have the code you've tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easiest way to achieve this is with Flexbox.

https://jsfiddle.net/Lnocagr2/2/

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
  <section>
    <div class="smallDiv">
      smalldiv
    </div>
    <div class="largeDiv">
      <ul>
        <li>bla foo bla bla foo bla bla foo bla bla foo bla bla foo bla bla foo bla bla foo bla bla foo bla bla foo bla bla foo bla bla foo bla bla foo bla bla foo bla bla foo bla bla foo bla bla foo bla bla foo bla bla foo bla bla foo bla bla foo bla bla foo bla bla foo bla bla foo bla bla foo bla bla foo bla bla foo bla bla foo bla</li>
        <li>foo</li>
        <li>bar</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </section>
  <section>
    <div class="smallDiv">
      smalldiv
    </div>
    <div class="largeDiv">
      <ul>
        <li>bla</li>
        <li>foo</li>
        <li>bar</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </section>
  <section>
    <div class="smallDiv">
      smalldiv
    </div>
    <div class="largeDiv">
      <ul>
        <li>bla</li>
        <li>foo</li>
        <li>bar</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </section>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.container{
  width:100%;
}
section{
  width:100%;
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:row;
}
.smallDiv{
  width:100px;
}
.largeDiv{
  flex:1;
}
```

Comment: If you take really long string as content of <li> of largeDiv - Content gets cropped as per browser window size and contents starts appearing below 'small div' which is not expected. that's my question - how to avoid them appearing below first div ( in your code - below 'smallDiv' )

Comment: Ah. Are you able to give them widths or use flexbox?

Comment: can't give them width. didn't use FlexBox - can you explain how to do it?

Comment: If you use flexbox - you can give the parent element display:flex; flex-direction:row; the small div a set width, and the second div flex:1 - that will tell the second element to just take whatever's left in the width.

Comment: Changed entire answer to flexbox. :-)

Comment: thanks, It worked well. I'm checking with variety of data and on different devices but as of now this is working good. Thank You.

Comment: Great! Glad to have helped.

Comment: I've added your solution and it's working fine for Chrome and FF, but for Safari and IE is not working, Could you please suggest the change ?.

Your JSFiddle not working on IE 10.