# How to have two divs in one line. right and left

Tags: html, css

```
<div className="content">
 <div style={{ float: "left" }}> {pedido.nombre}</div> //name
 <div style={{ float: "right" }}> ${pedido.precio}</div> //price
</div>
```

it should be name at left side and price on the right side, but it stays one side of the other
[image]

right there
[image]

Comment: https://flexbox.io/

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-apbokz?file=index.html if it really needs to be 'float'. Otherwise use flex like Robert and azium suggest - also see this guide: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: [So none of these worked for you?](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=two+divs+in+a+row)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to place two divs besides each other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5792367/how-to-place-two-divs-besides-each-other)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The key is to `justify-content: space-between`:

```css
.content {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <div style="background: yellow">Product name</div>
  <div style="background: orange">Price</div>
</div>
```

The two divs will have space in between.

Comment: i don't know how to, sorry, very noobie at this

Comment: @Drokoz take a look in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39853646/how-to-import-a-css-file-in-a-react-component) if you don't know how to import a css file into your components, or just do this in-line: <div className="content" style={{display:'flex', justifyContent:'space-between'}}>

Comment: Did you remove "float: left" and "float: right"? Try this way.

Comment: Nop, i tried a lot of things, i also have an accordion that it doesn't work. But is just in that part

Comment: It's working now, i deleted a div above that. Thanks a lot!! i really appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

While a flexbox approach works perfectly fine, I'd like to show how to achieve the described behaviour using `float`.

Here's the CSS

```
.float--left {
  float: left
}

.float--right {
  float: right
}

.clear {
  clear: both;
}
```

And some HTML

```
<div class="float--left">name</div>
<div class="float--right">price</div>

<div class="clear">other content</div>
```

***Note:** Added a example how to reset the float behaviour back to normal using clear *

Answer (score 0):

Flexbox will help you:

Here's the HTML:

```
<div class="content">
    <div class="left">
        Left Side
    </div>
    <div class="right">
        Right Side
    </div>
</div>
```

Here's the CSS:

```
.content{
    display: flex;
}

.right{
    margin-left: auto;
}
```